# How can I hide the command list in Alpine?

Tags: alpine-mail

I run Alpine across SSH on my phone which has a fairly limited screen size. The only issue that I have is the command list at the bottom takes up valuable screen real estate.

**Is there any way that I can turn the command list off (or toggle it)? ***

I seem to recall spotting an 'expert mode' type option or start flag that would turn it off, but I've slept since then and my relatively quick searches through the man page and duckduckgo.com have failed to turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `S` SETTINGS
2. `C` Config
3. Advanced User Preferences
4. Disable Keymenu
5. Press `X` to toggle
6. Press `E` to exit

Comment: Ah! *Keymenu*! I knew I saw it... just got the wrong name ;)